# Derive class from Revit api classes

Tags: c#, revit-api

it will be very useful to have an opportunity to derive your own classes from Revit api classes. Especially from Element Filter. I am trying to create subclass of element filter class that could filter elements by materials presented in family. Is there any way to do this using elementFilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot usefully derive your own classes from Revit API classes, no problem.

Adding useful additional filtering capabilities not provided by the Revit API requires access to Revit internals that you do not have.

You can create the additional functionality you seek using the available Revit API functionality and adding your own .NET-based enhancements to that.

Comment: Hello Jeremy, could you add an example of what you proposed ? I would be interested in deriving from the ElementCategoryFilter or the ElementParameterFilter for a specific floor type I made.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was a typo. I meant `cannot`, not `can`. Fixed it now. Please excuse the confusion. Sorry if I got your hopes up there.

Comment: Ok thank you. 
This was in the context of `AddTrigger` to an Updater. The API documentation says that only an CategoryFilter or ParameterFilter work with that function (here: https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/776a59e3-3214-8250-64ca-41ec913257d5.htm). Actually, for me the ClassFilter is also working.

Comment: I never noticed that caveat regarding the limitation to category and parameter filter. In fact, I doubt it is true. If anyone has time, it would be worth testing, proving that it is wrong, and reporting the documentation error to the development team.